# Regular users getting "Access is denied" when running program

Tags: permissions

We have a piece of software that's installed on a server, and users login to the terminal server to use it, i.e. everyone uses the same files. We recently updated the software by logging in as an admin user, uninstalled existing software, and running the installer of the newer version.

Now, admin users can use it no problem, but when a regular user uses it, they're getting all sorts of permission problems:

- When the program starts, it checks whether there're updates available by checking file version numbers, regular users get message saying update is available even though there isn't, as if it's unable to retrieve file's version number.
- The program also starts another .exe that's a COM automation object. When they try to start it they now get "Access is denied" error.

I checked the file permissions, normal users have read/execute permission. I tried changing them to full control but didn't make any difference.

Again, admin users don't have this problem. The software was working fine prior to the update.

I know this is a bit vague, but would appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions I should try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know where the access is denied.

Please use Process Monitor from Sysinternals (now Microsoft) to figure out which registry keys and files can't be accessed and modfiy the permissions based on this knowlege.

You can download it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx